# Adding an NSRect when a button is pushed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am trying to add an NSRect when a button is pushed but IBAction is in  one view controller while the drawing code must be in a view and for some reason the code I am using won't draw the rect here is the source for the action method in the view controller:

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender {

NSRect Rect =  NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

NSColor* BlackFill = [NSColor blackColor];

[BlackFill set];

NSRectFill(Rect);

NSColor* whitestroke = [NSColor whiteColor];

[whitestroke set];

NSFrameRectWithWidth(Rect, 5.0);

[rects addObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:Rect]];

[self.rectView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

And the source for the drawing code in the view:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

//heres the part where I want to draw the NSRect but it does not work

if ([datasource conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MainViewDatasource)]) {

    NSLog(@"DataSource conforms to protocol:MainViewDatasource");

    NSUInteger numRects = [datasource numberOfRectsInView:self];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numRects < 800; i++) {

        NSRect currentRect = [datasource rectangleView:self rectAtIndex:i];

        NSFrameRect(currentRect);
    }

    if (numRects >= 800) {

        NSAlert* alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];

        [alert setAlertStyle:NSInformationalAlertStyle];

        [alert setMessageText:@"You have placed too many rectangle shapes in your level"];

        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

        [alert release];
    }
}

/* The code here works great but has nothing to do with adding a rect when the button is           pressed */

NSRect Rect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 7000.0, 3500.0);

int width = Rect.size.width;

int height = Rect.size.height;

int i = 0;

[[NSColor blackColor] set];

NSBezierPath* drawingPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

for (i=0; i<=width; i=i+GRIDSIZE) {

    [drawingPath moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(i, 0)];

    [drawingPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(i, height)];
}

for (i=0; i<=height; i=i+GRIDSIZE) {

    [drawingPath moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(0, i)];

    [drawingPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(width, i)];
}

[drawingPath stroke];
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you get the "DataSource conforms…" message?

Comment: No, thats another one of my problems.

Comment: I have added code to the awakeFromNib method in my view controller that should have set up DataSource to conform to my protocol but for some reason it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds very much like your datasource is nil. A few possibilities:

1. You forgot to hook it up in Interface Builder
2. It isn't connected through Interface Builder, but through another controller — but *that* class (the controller) has a missing connection in Interface Builder
3. You simply forgot to assign it

Trace forward from where the datasource is supposed to be set to figure out where the chain of custody disappears.

Comment: You are right I tested to see if it was nil and it is I just can't figure out why.

Comment: What do you mean when you say I may have forgot to hook it up in Interface Builder.

Comment: @SageWashabaugh: I don't know how the datasource is supposed to be hooked up. If there's meant to be a connection in Interface Builder, it might not be made. If it's supposed to be in code, maybe that code isn't getting run when you think it is. I'm saying, start where the datasource is supposed to be assigned, make sure that's actually happening, then follow it forward until you see where it disappears.

Comment: There is not supposed to be a connection in Interface Builder its in code. I started where it is assigned and nothing is happening at all its nothing at all is happening. by the way datasource is a property that is being defined like this: @property(assign)id <MainViewDatasource> datasource; so the protocol named inside the brackets should make the property conform to it right? is there something I am missing here?